# Ipv4 Public ip cant be reached through HTTP

Tags: amazon-ec2

I tried all the combinations required while creating an EC2 instance. While creating an instance, I have choosen a new VPC which I had created which has an internet gateway and has both public and private subnet IDs. After giving proper security group, still then I am not able to connect to the instance.

Comment: Could you post the route table config?

Comment: You'll have to post route table config, security group config and netwok ACL if any. This will help others to know about exact problem.